# Commandments to eat

Tags: mitzvah, eating

I wonder if this question has ever been addressed by the commentators:

The Torah has 37 commandments “not to eat” specific things, but only 3 commandments “to eat” specific things:  We are enjoined to eat pessah, matzah, and maror at the seder table on Passover.

Why is this particular commemoration, Passover, associated so strongly with eating to the point of commanding eating?  No other Jewish holiday has this association.  The foods for all the other holidays are just customs.  We eat apples and honey on Rosh Hashanah, fruit on Sukkot, oil-fried foods on Hanukkah, hamantaschen on Purim, dairy products on Shavuot, etc.  But again, these are just customs, not commandments.

Comment: Possibly because the whole point of Pesach and the Seder is to relive the exodus experience and these foods allows us to feel us if we are there

Comment: What criteria are you using to classify something as "not to eat/to eat"? There are various other sacrifices/Terumos/Ma'asros that have an element of obligation to eat.

Comment: isn't the obligation to have 3 meals on Shabbat and holidays (or to eat in the sukkah) a commandment to eat? Isn't the obligation to maintain one's health a requirement to eat in general? Your question might be refined as "why is only holiday tied to the obligation to eat specific foods"?

Comment: Isn’t the obligation to eat matza and marror tied to the eating of the korban pesach? For sure Hillel held that way. Eating korbanos is a mitzvah by many korbanos. The Chassam Sofer seems to understand it as the only remenant of the mitzvohs of eating korbanos. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14666&st=&pgnum=149

Comment: May be a mitzvah to eat shviis lifi the Ramban...

Comment: Also eating erev yom kippur

Comment: Please clarify where you get these numbers from. Who says there are only three commandments involving eating?

Comment: Charedim counts 7-9 mitzvos to eat

Comment: Eating Kodshim (For Kohanim, and for owner according to Rashi), Eating on Erev Yom Kippur

Comment: The Torah has no mitzvah about eating either on Shabbat or Yom Tov. These ideas were Talmudically derived from the interpretations of *oneg* and *simcha*.

Comment: Don't forget there is a commandment to eat the first night of Sukkot.

Answer (score 0):

There are commandments to bring sacrifices and eat them. The Korban Pesach is one such Korban, that is brought on a specific day. Biblically, maror is only obligatory with the Korban Pesach. A better question would be from matzah, which must be eaten even independently of the Pesach. There the [Haggada of Pesach](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_Rabban_Gamliel%27s_Three_Things?lang=en) is clear that the reason is to remember that the Jews ate matzah when they  left Egypt.

Comment: This seems more like a comment.

Comment: The last sentence is the answer.